# ng-options directive not being updated

Tags: angularjs

I have a `<select>` box which I am populating with some objects. I group them, in this example by *Team*, using `group by`. However, when a players team change, the group is not updated.

This is the markup:

```
<select ng-options="player.name group by player.team for player in players"></select>
<button ng-click="change();">Change team name</button>
```

And the controller:

```
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.players = [{
        name: 'Player one',
        team: 'Denmark'
      },
      {
         name: 'Player two',
        team: 'Denmark'
      },
      {
        name: 'Player three',
        team: 'England'
      },
      {
        name: 'Player four',
        team: 'England'
      },
      {
        name: 'Player five',
        team: 'England'
      }
    ];

    $scope.change = function() {
      $scope.players[0].team = 'Sweden';
    };
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/fhyc96rx/) a JSFiddle demonstrating my problem.

Why is the team name not updating when changed?

Comment: Adding `track by player.team` at the end of the `ngOptions` expression seems to solve your issue, but the question is *why*...

Comment: @sp00m Using `track by player.team` breaks the selection. If you look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fhyc96rx/2/) example and try to select Player 3, Player 5 will be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the section "Complex Models (objects or collections)" in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

AngularJS only tracks the object by reference if neither "track by" is given or the "multiple" flag is set.

You have a couple of options:

An easy one would be to add "track by (player.name + '|' + player.team) but that is a little hackish.

Or else in your change method create a new object:
$scope.players[0] = { name: $scope.players[0].name, team: "Sweden" }